# Leaflet no tile (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I try to use leaflet with non-geographical image. When I follow the documentation I don't get the same result (https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html). I expect my output to be like below, but it's like the other picture

[image: i expect it to be]

[image: My output]

Are there any configuration for CRS ? or TileLayer?

Note: My source code is same as in official document(https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code, and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, the single image is added with a Leaflet [ImageOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay).

In your picture, the image is repeated infinitely, which is probably because it has been added as a Tile Layer instead.

If you really need a Tile Layer, you can use its bounds option to prevent loading extra tiles.